# Code seems good, but why does it ask for E two times and constantly prints 0.000?

Tags: c

I'm trying to debug my homework program. It looks good to me, but doesn't seem to work correctly.

Here is the task: `{Xn} = |COSn|/n ---->0` is a arithmetic sequence with '0' limit. The goal is to count all sequence's elements sum until some nth's element's absolute value becomes < then E (taken from the user).

Here is code:

```
/* {Xn} = |COSn|/n - is a sequence programm works with*/

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* adding libraries here*/

float calele(float a) // A function to CALculate an ELEment
{
    float b;
    b = fabs( cos(a) )/a; // {Xn} = |COSn|/n
    return b;
}

float seqsum(float E) //function, that counts sum. 
                      //"calele" function is used
{
    int n=1;
    float sum = 0.0;
    while( fabs(calele(n)) >= E) //if absolute value of counted element is still >= then user's E
    {
        sum = sum+calele(n); // then we add it so sum
        n = n+1;
    }
   return sum; // as soon as counted element becomes < then user's E, programm stops and returns the sum
}

int main(void)
{
    float E = 0; // Declaring E's variable
    float sum = 0; // sum of sequence's elements

    printf("Enter sequense's lower limit: "); // Prompting the user for the E
    scanf("%f", &E); // Getting E from the user
    sum = seqsum(E); // counting sum via function above
    printf("The sum of sequence's elements above %f is: %f\n\n", &E, &sum);

    return 0;
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. Why dosen't it work properly ?
2. Why is it constantly asking for second E?
3. Why does it print zeroes as a result no matter what ?

Comment: I cannot imagine that this program is constantly asking for input. The only `scanf` is not appearing in any loop...

Comment: Can you show your sample input/output session? The questions make a little sense.

Comment: Also please show the `/* adding libraries here*/` part.

Comment: I don't see how you print anything with `printf("The sum of sequence's elements above %f is: %f\n\n", &E, &sum);` please read warning, this should be `printf("The sum of sequence's elements above %f is: %f\n\n", E, sum);`

Comment: Just a suggestion: instead of writing a comment to explain that the job of `calele` Is to “CALculate an ELEment”, name it `calculate_element`.

Comment: Asking for E a second time indicates that you're running an old version of the code. Try deleting the executable, then recompile and make sure that you got a new executable. Note that you have two warnings, so if you're compiling with `-Werror` then you definitely won't get a new executable.

Comment: Having corrected the `printf` mistake when I enter `0.002` the output is `... 1.769577`. Note that `b <= 1.0` because of `fabs( cos(a) )/a;` where `a >= 1`. Any input > `0.54` gives an output of `0.000000`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. as it happens the libraries are not needed. Perhaps this is a MCVE from fuller code which might explain why OP says it runs twice.

Comment: You really, really need to take a step back. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @EugeneSh. here u are:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // stdlib.h provides abs() function

Comment: @EugeneSh. It works now, but i still have to type E twice. The prompt doesn't  appear at the second time, but the whole thing works only after i reenter my E.

typical output:

Enter sequense's lower limit: 0.002

0.002
The sum of sequence's elements above 0.002000 is: 1.769577

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Try `scanf(" %f", &E);` (note the leading space)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wow, it helped. would you please explain why such a mess happened without "leading space"?

Comment: The leading space in format string will "consume" all of the whitespace characters (including newline) which might happen to get stuck in your input stream. Not sure why you have these in your case, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the "Why is it constantly asking for second E" - thing.
Yet "Why does it print zeroes as a result no matter what" is because you pass `&E` and `&sum` to `printf`; I.e., you are passing pointers where float values are expected and thereby yield undefined behaviour.  Instead, write

```
printf("The sum of sequence's elements above %f is: %f\n\n", E, sum);
```